# echo an php array in value attribute and use it in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i am creating a system in which there is a table and data is displayed dynamically in the table now for every row there is checkbox! what actually i am doing this when the user check on specific rows through checkbox i want to get that whole row in the format of something like given below e.g

```
    object [
        0: {
        brandname:"brand_value",
        createdon:"createdon_value"
        .
        .
        .
             },
        {
    1:brandname:"brand_value",
        createdon:"createdon_value"
        .
        .
        .
        }
        ]
```

now what i done so far

**PHP**

```
 $obj = "{".$r['brand'].",".$r['production_date'].",".$r['expiry_date'].",".$r['madein'].",".$r['status'].",".$r['batch_code'].",".$r['created_on']."}";

echo "<th id='not2'><input type='checkbox' name='checkedvalues' value='".$obj."'/> </th>";
```

now what i am doing is i am creating an object(which is not working as i want it to be) and echoing out the value in every checkbox value attribute so that i can get that checked values in jquery

**JQuery Function**

```
$.each($("input[name='checkedvalues']:checked"), function(){
                    selectedvalues.push($(this).val());
                });
```

this is actually where the problem begins i need unique index with separated key and values e.g index 0 should contain data with key being **brand** and a value against it! because i need to access the the keys associated with an index individually ,now the problem!

```
selectedvalues.forEach(function(item, index, selectedvalues) {
                console.log(index , item);
            });
```

when i print this array it is showing me in the following format

```
 0 {asdsa,2017-09-05,2017-09-13,asda,asdsa,WRCTG8O,2017-09-27}
    1 {asdsa,2017-09-05,2017-09-13,asda,asdsa,WRCAbc2,2017-09-27}
```

it is actually creating an index and assigning all the values to that index whereas i want to access the values  in an index using keys e.g 0 index value through key ,which e.g is brand="brand_Value" ! just like we do in php we create an associative array an and in key we put index and in value we put another array with keys and values, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php

```
$obj = json_encode($r);
```

js

```
var ary = [];
ary['key'] = JSON.parse($(this).val());
selectedvalues.push(ary);
```

Comment: this code is assigning key to every value where as i want to make keys and values inside the value so that i can access them using names

Comment: you can set key for different value

Comment: 0 [key: "{asdsa,2017-09-05,2017-09-13,asda,asdsa,S4AQ9AR,2017-09-27}"]

Comment: this is what it is returning whereas i want to access e.g value of S4AQ9AR i dont have any way of doing it right now!

Comment: you can use parse json to send multiple value

Comment: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 1! basically i tried this before what it is doing is it is parsing every character inside the  
0 [key: "{asdsa,2017-09-05,2017-09-13,asda,asdsa,S4AQ9AR,2017-09-27}‌​"] so it doesnot work

Comment: awesome bro! just one thing! this is what is returning right now! 0  key: {id: "183", brand: "asdsa", product: "asdsa", production_date: "2017-09-05", expiry_date: "2017-09-13", …} this is exactky what i wanted now how do i access a value? e.g i need to get value of key brand at index 0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156024/discussion-between-uneeb-meer-and-azinkey).

Comment: thanks brother i did it using alert(Object.values(selectedvalues)[$i]['key'].id)